# Please, help to simplify set theory expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need to simplify set theory expression:
$ (\bar{B} \cap C) \cup \bar{D} \cup ((B \cup \bar{C})  \cap D)  \cup (A  \cup  \bar{C} )
$
$ \bar{B} $ means not B

I understand how to solve it graphically with Euler-Venn diagram. But I got stuck with solving it analytically using standard operators such as union, intersection, difference, complement of set.

I will be so grateful if you provide your solution step by step with used properties of algebraic structure like associative and commutative laws and etc.

Comment: What is $\overline B$? Do you mean complement of $B$?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 It means not B

Comment: What I got after simplification is that $A \cup B \cup C \cup {\overline {D}}.$ I think no further simplification can be made.

Comment: It may be universum or empty set in the end, ideally. Could you describe, your simplification step by step, please?

Comment: Apply distributive laws and associative laws again and again till it takes the simplest form.

Comment: Okey, it may be soluton path, thank you)

Comment: I got U as the answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not using the TeX codes , sorry . I hope you can understand this handwritten version.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly, what I need!)